# How to know how much data uploaded to web server in C#?

Tags: c#

I have C# desktop application. In which i have create HTML Form and submitted this form to upload data to web server. I want to show progress bar for data uploading. How to find out how much data uploaded to web server.

Comment: This can be done with Javascript. E.g. the HTML5 Drag Drop Demo illustrates the usage of XHR progress events. http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Comment: Just for clarification - the above comment is valid in the case you want to show the progress bar in the HTML form. Or do you want to report the progress to your desktop application.

Comment: i want to show progress in desktop application